# Why (ngModel) is not working?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have running the sample application to learn angular 2.  In my sample application `[(ngModel)]` is not working. But when i removes the square brackets `(ngModel)` the screen is loading but two way binding is not working.

should i do anything for making `[(ngModel)]` work.

Comment: That's because you have a mistake in your code ;-)

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: Post the code for your template and the component and people may be able to help. Just saying it 'is not working' the only possible answer is 'because you got it wrong' but we can't tell in what manner you got it wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably your code is missing this import line in your module:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

You also have to add FormsModule to module imports array:

```
@NgModule({
   imports:      [FormsModule, /*...*/ ],
   //...
})
```

Comment: Thanks Marius.  I have forget to add in module imports. :)

Comment: @Marius thank you so much for the answer. I was stuck and nervous for some time and it helped to proceed ahead.