# How to avoid ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when using [(ngModel)] binding on textarea

Tags: angular, data-binding

I have created a component that represents the form for modifying the details of an object.  The object exists in `app.component.ts`:

```
export class AppComponent {
  selectedItem: Item;
}
```

It is passed in via two-way binding into the component from `app.component.html` like so:

```
<item-details [(item)]="selectedItem"></item-details>
```

Within the component, the individual fields of the `Item` are bound to input controls, to allow the user to update the data, e.g.:

```
<mat-form-field class=name>
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="item.name" value="{{item.name}}" required placeholder="Name">
  <mat-error>Item name can not be left blank</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Everything works great until I get to the textarea:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
  <textarea id=description matInput [(ngModel)]="item.description" placeholder="Description">{{item.description}}</textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

It WORKS, but it throws an exception:

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
```

The error is not directly tied to the `<textarea>`, as it says that the value went from `false` to `true` and as such appears to be related to the `valid` property on the form, as hinted at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021564/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-from-angular).

Interestingly, I can avoid the error by modifying the contents of the `<textarea></textarea>` such as by putting a space after the contents:

```
<textarea ...>{{item.description}} </textarea>
```

But that only works if `item.description` is not `null`.  When it is `null` then I get the error again.

I'm triggering the change to `selectedItem` from another child component, which also has bi-directional binding on `selectedItem`.  When the user selects an item, the new `Item` flows up to the app, and back down to the detail component.

I have read [Everything you need to know about the 'ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError' error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) article.  To quote the article "I don't recommend using them but rather redesign your application".

Great!  How?  How do I structure things so that control A is used to select an `Item`, and control B is used to edit it?  What is the right way for controls A and B talk to one another without triggering this error?

Comment: Remove the value="{{item.name}}" from the input as it's making an infinite loop. ngModel is enough

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This error drove me absolutely crazy, and it only revealed itself after upgrading to Angular 5.  In my case, I am not using `[(ngModel)]`.  I am using the textarea for display purposes only (to get Material look and feel).  Nevertheless, this may be helpful for others searching endlessly like I have.

I discovered that if you bind to the `[value]` property of the textarea instead of using interpolation `{{}}`, the error goes away.

Instead of: `<textarea>{{value}}</textarea>`

Do: `<textarea [value]="value"></textarea>`

You didn't have any problems with `<input>` because it is a single-tag element and therefore must use property binding and not interpolation.  (To be clear, your use of interpolation together with `value` is only necessary because you are binding to an attribute which is evaluated only once.  Bind to `[value]`, which is a property, and you no longer need the `{{}}`. See the angular docs where this is explained very clearly.)

I suspect that with interpolation, angular sets the form as `false` on the first digest cycle, and on the second digest as `true` when it recognizes the value.  With `[value]` property binding, it recognizes the value on the first digest.

In any case, it works.

Comment: This wasn't applicable for me using angular 7, although it did help me identify my issue when using `<ng-container>` within a `<mat-form-field>`.

Comment: I relate to the first line as well "This error drove me absolutely crazy".
Mine was a text box, and luckily it was a readonly. So i changed it to [value].

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ngModel` then `{{item.description}}` is useless, should be enough:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
   <textarea id=description matInput [(ngModel)]="item.description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  Not in the `<textarea>`, nor in any of the `<input>`s.

Comment: Does that mean that the mat-form-field isn't being implemented right?

Comment: I mean, it renders correctly, but something clearly isn't right, because without `value="{{item.<field>}}"` the field has no value.

Comment: I think you must specify `name` attribute to make it work without value and interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is mostly occurring as a result of setting two different value to same parameter of a component during view initializing.

There is a really long explanation of problem and alternative solutions on [angular-university blog](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/) .

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds themselves here because they have a similar problem:

First thing to check is to make sure that the use of `[(ngModel)]="value"` works as shown in the docs.  If it does not, make sure you have imported `FormsModule`.  The *Angular Material* docs neglect to mention it, but `ngModel` doesn't work without it.

See also [Why (ngModel) is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43994919/why-ngmodel-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I had this error:

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError ... Previous value: 'aria-describedby: null' Current value: 'aria-describedby: mat-error-22'
```

the problem was that I was manually validating my form immediately after creation of the form and before loading of mat-form-field components. In my case, I actually didn't have to validate my form so I removed it.